# Elixir/Ecto: How can I batch the preloading of an association?

Tags: elixir, ecto, preload

In my database, a Post has many Comments. For a nightly-cleanup task I need to load a large number of Posts into a list, and preload all Comments associated with each.

```js
Post.filter(needs_review: true)
|> Ecto.preload(:comments)
|> Repo.all()
```

The query to load the Posts runs fine (around 200ms) but the query to load all associated Comments times out (60+ secs), understandably, because it's trying to load *millions* of Comments all in one query.

Is there a way to tell `Ecto.preload()` to split the preloading operation into batches, so that it will load the comments in multiple manageable-sized queries? I'm picturing something like the following:

```js
Post.filter(needs_review: true)
|> Ecto.preload({:comments, [batch_size: 1000]})
|> Repo.all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, yes. I'm delighted to find that [`Ecto.preload` supports passing a function](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries) so you can write whatever querying logic you want. The preload function is given a list of IDs of the *parent* association. Using this trick, the code below tells `Ecto.preload` to load the comments for 50 posts at a time, which is small enough to avoid timeouts for my use case.

```js
def load_posts do
  Post.filter(needs_review: true)
  |> preload(comments: ^& batched_preload_comments(&1))
  |> Repo.all()
end

defp batched_preload_comments(post_ids) do
  post_ids
  |> Enum.chunk_every(100)
  |> Enum.map(& Comment |> where([c], c.post_id in ^&1) |> Repo.all())
  |> List.flatten()
end
```